# NoClassDefFoundError when Maven test-scoped dependency overrides transitive compile-scoped dependency

Tags: java, maven

We have several deployables, and have extracted common code into several libraries.  Deployable app A has a (default-scoped) Maven dependency on library B, and a test-scoped dependency on library C.

I made a change to library B, which used a method from, and so created a dependency on, library C.  This caused app A to fail at run-time with NoClassDefFoundErrors.  App A's unit tests all passed, of course, so we only found this in our staging environment.  (Other apps either had no direct dependency on library C, or had a default-scoped dependency on it, and so continued to work.)

The obvious fix worked, of course: I edited A's pom.xml to make the dependency on C default scope.

My question is: Are we doing something wrong?  Or is this how things are supposed to work?  Is anyone aware of an automated way of detecting the potential problem at build-time and failing the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing something wrong. Maven made a peculiar design choice here. See also

[Maven: test vs. transitive compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40461621/maven-test-vs-transitive-compile), especially Tunakis comment on my question.

and

[Maven dependency within dependency with different scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396901/maven-dependency-within-dependency-with-different-scope)

My advice: Eliminate C from A's pom.xml. Only add test dependencies if these dependencies are not already on the dependency tree.

Comment: It is really confusing to have A import classes from C but not declare C in its pom but instead rely on it being pulled from transitive dependency.

Comment: It is. I would have defined "test" to be a scope completely ignored when non-test code runs, but instead they chose that all direct scopes override transitive scopes.

Comment: So in our case, A's test dependency on C came before A's dependency on B, and both came before B's dependency on C.  And that last change broke things for us at runtime.  As a follow-up question: Is anyone aware of an automated way of detecting the potential problem at build-time?